# How to reshape a variable to, say, mean = 5, sd = 10?

Tags: r, data-transformation

The problem I am having is that I have a distribution that I want to remain the same shape, but the mean and variance altered. When I use `scale()` in R, it can change to a standard normal, but I am having trouble to get other distributions (as when you change the mean, it also affects the standard deviation and vice versa).

Comment: When you add a constant to all values, that changes *only* the mean and not the SD.  When you rescale all values, that changes all moments but in a predictable way. In particular, it will not change the mean if the mean is already zero.  So, why not (a) shift the variable to make the mean zero, then (b) rescale it to make the SD equal to 10 (leaving the mean equal to zero), then (c) shift the mean to 5?

Comment: That is indeed the answer.