# How to scale a variable to a specific mean and standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, standardization, arithmetic

Let's say I have one variable that has a known metric (e.g., variable A has a mean of .7 and standard deviation of .3). How do I scale a second variable (variable B) to have the same mean and standard deviation?

I know how to make both variables have a mean of zero and standard deviation of one. (That's easy--translate them to z scores), but I can't think of how to center them around a particular value with a particular sd. Thanks!

Comment: 0.7 + 0.3 * (B - B_mean) / B_SD

Comment: Pleased that you got what you wanted, but I am not sure what long-term value this question has for the forum.

Comment: @dfife It is not so easy because under some circumstances it is better to use the geometric mean

Comment: Also see [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59631/how-to-reshape-a-variable-to-say-mean-5-sd-10) for example ... which has been marked as a duplicate of a different question (though I believe the one I link above is more like it)